# vb.net database commandtext property has not been initialized (system.data.dll)

Tags: vb.net

When I try to run this code I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
```

Additional information: `ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized`

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand


        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\database test\ikeagoed\ikeagoed\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() <<error at this line
        If Not reader.HasRows Then
            'the data does not exist.
            MsgBox("bestaat niet!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
        Else
            'The record exists
            MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
        End If

        con.Close()

    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want the reader to return? Do you have a sql query to execute?

Comment: Read the actual words of the error message you used as your title, and then ask yourself where in your code you initialize (assign a value to) the `CommandText` property. The words in the message make it *extremely* clear what the problem is - it's absolutely required for you to learn to actually read those words. They're not just random letters; they actually provide meaningful information.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code do you tell the sql server what it is that you're searching for.

Somewhere you need a sql query there

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where userName = @userName" ' This query will be used for finding all users with that user name
```

Is just an example of something you can do. You'll want to look up sql parameters as well

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) is just one of many sites for learning sql